# Linking error on Firebase 3.7.0 for iOS Application

Tags: ios, firebase

I'm trying to use Firebase SDK 3.7.0 in my iOS application, but it gives linking errors.

I've followed the steps described on the README.md that it's included on the framework SDK downloaded from https://firebase.google.com/docs/ios/setup, on integration without CocoaPods section.

On linking, appears these errors:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
  "_sqlite3_bind_double", referenced from:
      ___48-[FIRASqliteStore bindValues:toStatement:error:]_block_invoke in FirebaseAnalytics(FIRASqliteStore_2e8a0f466f3be880241569cb2066f73b.o)
  "_sqlite3_bind_null", referenced from:
      ___48-[FIRASqliteStore bindValues:toStatement:error:]_block_invoke in FirebaseAnalytics(FIRASqliteStore_2e8a0f466f3be880241569cb2066f73b.o)
  "_sqlite3_column_type", referenced from:
      -[FIRASqliteStore valueAtColumn:forStatement:] in FirebaseAnalytics(FIRASqliteStore_2e8a0f466f3be880241569cb2066f73b.o)
  "_sqlite3_column_double", referenced from:
      -[FIRASqliteStore valueAtColumn:forStatement:] in FirebaseAnalytics(FIRASqliteStore_2e8a0f466f3be880241569cb2066f73b.o)
  "_sqlite3_open_v2", referenced from:
      -[FIRASqliteStore openAndValidateDatabase:] in FirebaseAnalytics(FIRASqliteStore_2e8a0f466f3be880241569cb2066f73b.o)
  "_sqlite3_clear_bindings", referenced from:
      -[FIRASqliteStore cleanUpStatement:forQuery:] in FirebaseAnalytics(FIRASqliteStore_2e8a0f466f3be880241569cb2066f73b.o)
      -[FIRASqliteStore bindValues:toStatement:error:] in FirebaseAnalytics(FIRASqliteStore_2e8a0f466f3be880241569cb2066f73b.o)
  "_sqlite3_column_count", referenced from:
      -[FIRASqliteStore recordsForQuery:parameterValues:error:withFilter:] in FirebaseAnalytics(FIRASqliteStore_2e8a0f466f3be880241569cb2066f73b.o)
      -[FIRASqliteStore validateDatabaseWithError:] in FirebaseAnalytics(FIRASqliteStore_2e8a0f466f3be880241569cb2066f73b.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_SSReadingList", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in GoogleSignIn(please_link_SafariServices.framework_.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_MFMessageComposeViewController", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in FirebaseInvites(GINInviteController_af66380ba390cf14b066932397806d20.o)
      objc-class-ref in FirebaseInvites(GPPACLSearchViewController_3fc71921176f5b855c444ab9ce9260c7.o)
      objc-class-ref in FirebaseInvites(GINInviteScrollView_5b90efc8e1a69f9dfe581b021e7f869b.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_CMMotionManager", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in FirebaseDynamicLinks(GPPSpamSignal_a0a54565a3243ede865cc9b2724bc7a8.o)
  "_sqlite3_column_bytes", referenced from:
      -[FIRMessagingRmq2PersistentStore scanOutgoingRmqMessagesWithHandler:] in FirebaseMessaging(FIRMessagingRmq2PersistentStore_66612bb0cdda59e6a475d66db9ec25d4.o)
      -[FIRASqliteStore valueAtColumn:forStatement:] in FirebaseAnalytics(FIRASqliteStore_2e8a0f466f3be880241569cb2066f73b.o)
  "_sqlite3_reset", referenced from:
      -[FIRASqliteStore cleanUpStatement:forQuery:] in FirebaseAnalytics(FIRASqliteStore_2e8a0f466f3be880241569cb2066f73b.o)
  "_sqlite3_changes", referenced from:
      -[FIRMessagingRmq2PersistentStore deleteMessagesFromTable:withRmqIds:] in FirebaseMessaging(FIRMessagingRmq2PersistentStore_66612bb0cdda59e6a475d66db9ec25d4.o)
      -[FIRMessagingRmq2PersistentStore deleteExpiredOrFinishedSyncMessages:] in FirebaseMessaging(FIRMessagingRmq2PersistentStore_66612bb0cdda59e6a475d66db9ec25d4.o)
      -[FIRASqliteStore deleteRecordsFromTableWithName:condition:parameterValues:error:] in FirebaseAnalytics(FIRASqliteStore_2e8a0f466f3be880241569cb2066f73b.o)
  "_sqlite3_errmsg", referenced from:
      -[FIRMessagingRmq2PersistentStore saveMessageWithRmqId:tag:data:error:] in FirebaseMessaging(FIRMessagingRmq2PersistentStore_66612bb0cdda59e6a475d66db9ec25d4.o)
      -[FIRMessagingRmq2PersistentStore lastErrorMessage] in FirebaseMessaging(FIRMessagingRmq2PersistentStore_66612bb0cdda59e6a475d66db9ec25d4.o)
```

The XCode version is 7.0.1

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need to add this framework as you are not using pods

> libicucore.tbd
>
> CFNetwork.framework
>
> Security.framework
>
> SystemConfiguration.framework
>
> libc++.tbd
>
> libsqlite3.tbd

For 2020, if you even then get the infuriating errors for:

> _OBJC_CLASS_$_SKPaymentQueue
>   _OBJC_CLASS_$_SKProductsRequest

then, additionally add **StoreKit**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you have to add all those frameworks, even if you're not using pods. I sorted that out adding just libsqlite3.dylb and libs.1.dylib