# Libraries required to resolve firebase-crash linker issues when added manually

Tags: ios, objective-c, firebase, firebase-crash-reporting

Have added libs mentioned in [Linking error on Firebase 3.7.0 for iOS Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40509021/linking-error-on-firebase-3-7-0-for-ios-application) but still I get below linker errors for adding firebase crash.

> "_FIRLogError", referenced from:
>         -[FCRBreakpadController enableDebugger] in FirebaseCrash(FCRBreakpadController_bc3acad0fa3a54a5c7c331f54af621b0.o)
>         -[FCRBreakpadController startWithConfiguration:] in FirebaseCrash(FCRBreakpadController_bc3acad0fa3a54a5c7c331f54af621b0.o)
>         -[FCRBreakpadController createDirectory:] in FirebaseCrash(FCRBreakpadController_bc3acad0fa3a54a5c7c331f54af621b0.o)
>         +[FCRAnalytics messageDictionaryFromMessage:] in FirebaseCrash(FCRAnalytics_281d4dbe093b1d2a74ef0873d1ac6263.o)
>         -[FCRClient startWithConfiguration:error:] in FirebaseCrash(FCRClient_482ceec6b5943edbfb1d1dff6beb18f6.o)
>         -[FCRCrashDump crashInfoFromSystemMetadata:] in FirebaseCrash(FCRCrashDump_ee5f791af340383d1b426338c1150e39.o)
>         -[FCRUploadQueue initWithDirectory:maxSize:] in FirebaseCrash(FCRUploadQueue_2ce78e78dbb8f27676bd42e0302357a3.o)
>         ...   "_FIRLogInfo", referenced from:
>         -[FCRClient startWithConfiguration:error:] in FirebaseCrash(FCRClient_482ceec6b5943edbfb1d1dff6beb18f6.o)
>         ___49-[FCRBulkUploader uploadFileFromQueue:onSuccess:]_block_invoke in
>   FirebaseCrash(FCRBulkUploader_af76d0815dcb863205f4ed96c30df68e.o)
>   "_GSDK_objc_getClass", referenced from:
>         _____GetFIRAnalyticsClass_block_invoke in FirebaseCrash(FCRAnalytics_281d4dbe093b1d2a74ef0873d1ac6263.o)
>   "_OBJC_CLASS_$_FIRApp", referenced from:
>         objc-class-ref in NFAppDelegate.o
>         objc-class-ref in FirebaseCrash(FCRClient_482ceec6b5943edbfb1d1dff6beb18f6.o)
>   "_OBJC_CLASS_$_FIRInstanceID", referenced from:
>         objc-class-ref in FirebaseCrash(FCRCrashUploader_810ae32cc5e6c7f23936333033b9ebd7.o)
>   "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GSDK_PBDescriptor", referenced from:
>         objc-class-ref in FirebaseCrash(Sdk.pb_8328b2bef1af4d0941a97cc98e810c6c.o)
>   "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GSDK_PBGeneratedMessage", referenced from:
>         _OBJC_CLASS_$_FCRMSGTimestamp in FirebaseCrash(Sdk.pb_8328b2bef1af4d0941a97cc98e810c6c.o)
>         _OBJC_CLASS_$_FCRMSGCrashReport in FirebaseCrash(Sdk.pb_8328b2bef1af4d0941a97cc98e810c6c.o)
>         _OBJC_CLASS_$_FCRMSGDevice in FirebaseCrash(Sdk.pb_8328b2bef1af4d0941a97cc98e810c6c.o)
>         _OBJC_CLASS_$_FCRMSGAndroidDevice in FirebaseCrash(Sdk.pb_8328b2bef1af4d0941a97cc98e810c6c.o)
>         _OBJC_CLASS_$_FCRMSGIOSDevice in FirebaseCrash(Sdk.pb_8328b2bef1af4d0941a97cc98e810c6c.o)
>         _OBJC_CLASS_$_FCRMSGApplication in FirebaseCrash(Sdk.pb_8328b2bef1af4d0941a97cc98e810c6c.o)
>         _OBJC_CLASS_$_FCRMSGAndroidApplication in FirebaseCrash(Sdk.pb_8328b2bef1af4d0941a97cc98e810c6c.o)
>         ...   "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GSDK_PBMutableArray", referenced from:
>         objc-class-ref in FirebaseCrash(FCRCrashDump_ee5f791af340383d1b426338c1150e39.o)
>   "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GSDK_PBRootObject", referenced from:
>         _OBJC_CLASS_$_FCRMSGSdkRoot in FirebaseCrash(Sdk.pb_8328b2bef1af4d0941a97cc98e810c6c.o)
>   "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GTMLogBasicFormatter", referenced from:
>         objc-class-ref in FirebaseCrash(FCRSystemLogger_6532fb37dc095ffa73463b57baf5fca7.o)
>   "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GTMLogNoFilter", referenced from:
>         objc-class-ref in FirebaseCrash(FCRSystemLogger_6532fb37dc095ffa73463b57baf5fca7.o)
>   "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GTMLogger", referenced from:
>         objc-class-ref in FirebaseCrash(FCRSystemLogger_6532fb37dc095ffa73463b57baf5fca7.o)
>         objc-class-ref in FirebaseCrash(uploader_089041b840f448492d858d7daf481e47.o)
>   "_OBJC_METACLASS_$_GSDK_PBGeneratedMessage", referenced from:
>         _OBJC_METACLASS_$_FCRMSGTimestamp in FirebaseCrash(Sdk.pb_8328b2bef1af4d0941a97cc98e810c6c.o)
>         _OBJC_METACLASS_$_FCRMSGCrashReport in FirebaseCrash(Sdk.pb_8328b2bef1af4d0941a97cc98e810c6c.o)
>         _OBJC_METACLASS_$_FCRMSGDevice in FirebaseCrash(Sdk.pb_8328b2bef1af4d0941a97cc98e810c6c.o)
>         _OBJC_METACLASS_$_FCRMSGAndroidDevice in FirebaseCrash(Sdk.pb_8328b2bef1af4d0941a97cc98e810c6c.o)
>         _OBJC_METACLASS_$_FCRMSGIOSDevice in FirebaseCrash(Sdk.pb_8328b2bef1af4d0941a97cc98e810c6c.o)
>         _OBJC_METACLASS_$_FCRMSGApplication in FirebaseCrash(Sdk.pb_8328b2bef1af4d0941a97cc98e810c6c.o)
>         _OBJC_METACLASS_$_FCRMSGAndroidApplication in FirebaseCrash(Sdk.pb_8328b2bef1af4d0941a97cc98e810c6c.o)
>         ...   "_OBJC_METACLASS_$_GSDK_PBRootObject", referenced from:
>         _OBJC_METACLASS_$_FCRMSGSdkRoot in FirebaseCrash(Sdk.pb_8328b2bef1af4d0941a97cc98e810c6c.o)
>   "_kFIRAppNameKey", referenced from:
>         ___17+[FCRClient load]_block_invoke in FirebaseCrash(FCRClient_482ceec6b5943edbfb1d1dff6beb18f6.o)
>   "_kFIRAppReadyToConfigureSDKNotification", referenced from:
>         +[FCRClient load] in FirebaseCrash(FCRClient_482ceec6b5943edbfb1d1dff6beb18f6.o)
>   "_kFIRLoggerCrash", referenced from:
>         -[FCRBreakpadController enableDebugger] in FirebaseCrash(FCRBreakpadController_bc3acad0fa3a54a5c7c331f54af621b0.o)
>         -[FCRBreakpadController startWithConfiguration:] in FirebaseCrash(FCRBreakpadController_bc3acad0fa3a54a5c7c331f54af621b0.o)
>         -[FCRBreakpadController createDirectory:] in FirebaseCrash(FCRBreakpadController_bc3acad0fa3a54a5c7c331f54af621b0.o)
>         +[FCRAnalytics messageDictionaryFromMessage:] in FirebaseCrash(FCRAnalytics_281d4dbe093b1d2a74ef0873d1ac6263.o)
>         -[FCRClient startWithConfiguration:error:] in FirebaseCrash(FCRClient_482ceec6b5943edbfb1d1dff6beb18f6.o)
>         -[FCRCrashDump crashInfoFromSystemMetadata:] in FirebaseCrash(FCRCrashDump_ee5f791af340383d1b426338c1150e39.o)
>         ___49-[FCRBulkUploader uploadFileFromQueue:onSuccess:]_block_invoke in
>   FirebaseCrash(FCRBulkUploader_af76d0815dcb863205f4ed96c30df68e.o)
>         ... ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64 clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see
>   invocation)

Have set framework search path and library search path as below
[image]

Comment: question is simple need to find depended libs for firebase-crash .. old stackoverflow answer still results in above error

Comment: there could be no code here.. it is about firebase when not added with PODS

Comment: @mkumar , how have you add this firebase into your project?

Comment: using steps as in https://firebase.google.com/docs/ios/setup#frameworks

Comment: @mkumar , it have to work. I've missed something

Comment: want to do without cocoapods .... issue is with adding firebase-crash sdk manually

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try cocoapods manager:
`pod 'Firebase', '~> 3.9'`

it could simply fix all of your wrong dependcies.

https://cocoapods.org/pods/Firebase

or check readme.md file:
you have to add all these libs:

> "(~> X)" below means that the SDK requires all of the frameworks from
>   X. You should make sure to include all of the frameworks from X when
>   including the SDK.
>
> ### Analytics
>
> - FirebaseAnalytics.framework
> - FirebaseCore.framework
> - FirebaseInstanceID.framework
> - GoogleInterchangeUtilities.framework
> - GoogleSymbolUtilities.framework
> - GoogleToolboxForMac.framework
>
>   ### Crash (~> Analytics)
> - FirebaseCrash.framework

Comment: @mkumar , so put screenshots of your project properties. It seem, you have not set properly both `library search path` and `framework search path`

Comment: added screen shot for the same.. even added srcroot recursively.. but didn't help though

Comment: @mkumar , what about the other analytics' frameworks?

Comment: looking to use firebase only for crash reporting.. do i still need to add others to it ?

Comment: @mkumar ,read Readme.md file more carefully. You have to add about 5 libs . I've updated the post